# How to make a working Cooldown System for Magnet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Powerup : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private float _powerupSpeed = 3.0f;

    //ID for Powerups
    //0 = Triple shot
    //1 = speed
    //2 = Shields
    [SerializeField] // 0 = Triple Shot 1 - Speed 2 - Shields
    private int powerupID;


    private Powerup _powerup;


    private Player _player;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _thePlayer;

    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip _powerupSX;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _spaceMagnet = 1.0f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _magnetRate = 0.5f;

    private float _canMagnet = -1; 
   

  

   

    void Start()
    {
        _thePlayer = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

        if (_thePlayer == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Player is null");
        }
        
        _player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Player>();

        

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // move down at a speed of 3 
        // When we leave the screen, destroy this object 
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * _powerupSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        _powerupSpeed = Random.Range(2.0f, 5f);

        if (transform.position.y < -3f)
        {

            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }

        
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C) && Time.time > _canMagnet)  
        {
            _canMagnet = Time.time + _magnetRate;
            TrackerBeam();
        }
       
    }

    //OnTriggerCollision
    //Only be collectable by the Player (HINT: Use Tags)
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            //communicate with the playerscript
            //handle to the component i want
            //assign the handle to the compnent

            Player player = other.transform.GetComponent<Player>();

            if (player != null)
            {


                switch (powerupID)
                {
                    case 0:
                        player.tripleshotActive();
                        _player.AddScore(5);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        player.speedboostActive();
                        _player.AddScore(1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        player.shieldsActive();
                        _player.AddScore(3);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        player.reloadActive();
                        player.AddScore(2);
                        Debug.Log("Ammo Colleted");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        player.AddingHealth();
                        player.AddScore(4);
                        Debug.Log("Adding Health");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        player.HeavyFire();
                        player.AddScore(6);
                        Debug.Log("Heavy Fire Actived");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        player.DangerBall();
                        player.AddScore(-10);
                        Debug.Log("Direct Hit");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Debug.Log("Default Value");
                        break;


                }
            }
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(_powerupSX, transform.position);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else 
        {
            other.gameObject.TryGetComponent<Laser>(out Laser _isEnemyLaser);

            if(_isEnemyLaser != null)
            {
                Destroy(this.gameObject);
            }
            _player.AddScore(-20);

        }

        

    }

    private void TrackerBeam()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(this.transform.position, _thePlayer.transform.position, _spaceMagnet * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    
   
}
```

I'm trying to create a Cooldown System for the Power-up Magnet I created. Even though I researched all over the internet for different way to get this cooldown to work none of them have been working for me. In some of them, the cooldown code would break the magnet and in some, the magnet would still work but the cooldown still doesn't work. Would it be better for me to make it a separate code instead of in the Power-up Scripted where the magnet script is located? If you can help it would be appreciated.

Comment: Some caveats with your code: tags should not be compared with "==": `if (other.tag == "Player")` should be `if (other.CompareTag("Player")`. Shouldn't `_player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Player>();` be `_player = _thePlayer.GetComponent<Player>();` ? There is no need for an explicit this: `Destroy(gameObject);` is enough (same for `this.transform` -> just `transform`). Also, add a `return` after `Destroy(gameObject);` calls.  `_player.AddScore(-20);` should be before the **if**.

Answer (score 1):

Use coroutines for cooldown

```cs
private float cooldownTime = 5f;

private IEnumerator MagnetCooldownRi() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(cooldownTime); // "yields" (waits)
    // Program continues after waiting
    // ... do something after cooldown ... 
}
```

Call it like this, once.

```cs
StartCoroutine(MagnetCooldownRi());
```

[Unity Coroutines Documentation with examples](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

Answer (score 1):

CoRoutines are one way to go, I prefer the old fashioned way: by using the current delta time.

```
internal class MyMB : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float StartingValue = 20.0f;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (StartingValue >= 0.0f)
            StartingValue -= Time.deltaTime;
        else
            DoWhatever();
    }
    
    private void DoWhatever()
    {
        Debug.Log("Done!");
    }
}
```

Of course, you can do it the other way around as well: starting from 0.0f and increasing it by `Time.deltaTime` until it's over some magical maximum value.